# How do I console output log from another module - raise AssertionError

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

Trying to run robot code in python.

When running the following code, on the output console I get 'No handlers could be found for logger "RobotFramework"'
How do I log/print to console the raise AssertionError from another module?
Or log all logs sent to logger "RobotFramework"

```
from ExtendedSelenium2Library import ExtendedSelenium2Library
from robot.api import logger

class firsttest():


    def googleit(self):
        self.use_url = 'https://google.ca'
        self.use_browser = 'chrome'

        s2l = ExtendedSelenium2Library()
        s2l.open_browser(self.use_url, self.use_browser)
        s2l.maximize_browser_window()

        try:
            s2l.page_should_contain('this text does not exist on page')
        except:
            logger.console('failed')


runit = firsttest()
runit.googleit()
```

Get following console output:

```
failed
No handlers could be found for logger "RobotFramework"
```

Comment: Try this at start of the code `import logging; logging.getLogger("RobotFramework").addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())`

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: Thank you pointed me to the right direction by adding "RobotFramework" as a handler, plus followed python document [link](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)